# How do you find the first event & time of that event for each user?

Tags: sql, timestamp

| user | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-2-10 | answered |
| 1 | 2021-2-15 | answered |
| 2 | 2021-2-11 | answered |
| 2 | 2021-2-14 | answered |
| 2 | 2021-2-12 | unanswered |
| 3 | 2021-2-16 | next question |
| 3 | 2021-2-13 | next question |
| 4 | 2021-2-12 | next question |
| 4 | 2021-2-17 | answered |

Comment: Please tag your question with the dbms that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider

Query 1. Using window functions such as `ROW_NUMBER` to order and filter your rows
Query 2. Filtering your records using an aggregate query that finds the earliest start date

See working fiddle below with one way to accomplish the suggested approach above.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    user,
    timestamp,
    event
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user ORDER BY timestamp) rn
    FROM
        my_table
) t
WHERE
    rn=1;
```

| user | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-10 | answered |
| 2 | 2021-02-11 | answered |
| 3 | 2021-02-13 | next question |
| 4 | 2021-02-12 | next question |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    t1.user,
    t1.timestamp,
    t1.event
FROM 
    my_table t1
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            user,
            MIN(timestamp) as min_timestamp
        FROM
            my_table
        GROUP BY
            user
    ) t2 ON t1.user=t2.user AND
            t1.timestamp=t2.min_timestamp;
```

| user | timestamp | event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-10 | answered |
| 2 | 2021-02-11 | answered |
| 3 | 2021-02-13 | next question |
| 4 | 2021-02-12 | next question |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oh3dvDL1mLH3kuk1Rzsi3E/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on MySQL 5.6:

```
select * from (
  select * from events
  order by user, timestamp
) a
group by user
having timestamp = min(timestamp);
```

EDIT
MySQL 8.0 version:

```
select e1.user, e1.timestamp, event from (
  select user, min(timestamp) timestamp
  from events
  group by user
) e1
  left join (select * from events) e2
  on e2.user = e1.user
  and e2.timestamp = e1.timestamp
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rq94bbCHhFL8rwcFoBC4yN/0)

Comment: [Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb17d5/18/0)

Comment: This works on Mysql 5.6 but I get the following error on 5.7 and 8.0 [`Query Error: Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'a.timestamp' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hcjS5bYHGt7SPBKPcW6tVE/1). I recommend including the version number for mysql also in your answer since this may not work out of the box on newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

- First you will create rank for each row based on timestamp and id
- Then we just choose the rank = 1

```
WITH data as (

SELECT 
*,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER(PARTITION BY USER ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) as rank_
FROM my_table
)

SELECT * from data where rank_ = 1
```